# Displaying two different tables on different click

Tags: web, frontend

So I'm creating website for a sports team. I have a "Results" page, where their scores for every round will be posted in form of table. Above the table I need to have two options, one that says "Season 2014/2015" and the other "Season 2015/2016", and I want two different tables displayed for each one of them? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by simply using jquery.Here is an example.

HTML

```
<div id="foo">
        <span id="table1-btn">Table 1</span>
        <span id="table2-btn">Table 2</span>
    </div>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td>Table 1</td><td>Table 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 1</td><td>Table 1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table2">
        <tr>
            <td>Table 2</td><td>Table 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table 2</td><td>Table 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

css

```
#foo{
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
#table1-btn,
#table2-btn{
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#e3e3e3;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table2').hide();

    $('#table1-btn').click(function () {
       $('#table2').hide();
       $('#table1').show();
    });
    $('#table2-btn').click(function () {
       $('#table1').hide();
       $('#table2').show();
    });
});
```

Find jsfiddle code [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Puni/rzrunjc8/)

Comment: Seems like it's what I've been looking for, thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad that it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, you could look into tabs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Have your tables in a tab 2014/2015 and the other tables in a tab 2015/2016

Comment: The problem is that I'm not using bootstrap. You think Javascript will be necessary for thia?

Comment: I believe that you will have to use a bit of javascript to acheive working tabs.If you don't want to use bootstrap you could take a look at this alternative:
[http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery](http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery)